# How to find if a user is logged in from an iframe in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, php, drupal-7

I am showing an iframe which is also hosted on the same domain.
I want to find out from inside the iframe (which has a ResponsiveFilemanager) whether the user is admin or not. So that the Upload/Delete features can be enabled/disabled.

Any ideas? Thx

Comment: $user->roles is what you are looking for.

Comment: @dr_dev i cannot use this from inside the iframe, because iframe doesn't load drupal bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript postMessage method to transfer data between iframe and main window.
Syntax
otherWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);